# Array Vacío tras consumir Alamofire en Swift

Tags: json, api, ios, swift4, alamofire

Buen día amigos, tengo una duda sobre el consumo de JSON usando Alamofire en Swift. Si hago debug a mi código si me llena mi array con la información que proviene del JSON pero al pasar el procesamiento me devuelve mi lista con 0 elementos, a continuación mis fragmentos de código. Muchas gracias

CLASE ARTISTA.swift (mi array "artistas" es global)

```
import Foundation

var artistas:Array<Artista>=[]

class Artista{
    var artista: String?
    var descripcion: String?
    var idArtista: Int = 0
    var imagen: String?
    var website: String?
}
```

Función en donde consumo el JSON utilizando Alamofire (Si debugeamos acá mi lista cuenta con mis elementos provenientes de mi archivo JSON

```
    func getArtistas(){
    let url = "http://192.168.0.19:3000/api/artists"
    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { response in
        let data = Data(response.data!)

        do {
            let jsonArtistas = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as! [[String:Any]]

            for x in jsonArtistas {
                let nombre = x["artista"] as! String
                let descripcion = x["descripcion"] as! String
                let id = x["idArtista"] as! String
                let imagen = x["imagen"] as! String
                let website = x["website"] as! String


                let artista = Artista()
                artista.artista = nombre
                artista.descripcion = descripcion
                artista.idArtista = Int(id)!
                artista.imagen = imagen
                artista.website = website

                artistas.append(artista)
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error", error)
        }


    }
}
```

Uso de CollectionView (Aquí es donde regresa el valor 0)

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return artistas.count
}
```

Comment: Entendemos que el JOSN es correcto y que no sales por el error, verdad? Una segunda cosa, seguro que el método numberOfItemsInSection se llama después de haber terminado el Alamofire y de haber procesado el JSON, verdad?

Comment: No comprendo tu segunda pregunta amigo, en qué momento cierro las peticiones de Alamofire porque tengo entendido que al implementarlo en el ViewDidLoad se hace la ejecución antes

Comment: Llamas al Alamofire usando un bloque? Si es asi, la ejecución continua mientras el Alamofire hace lo que tenga que hacer. Si no lo haces asi, deberías, ya que te va a colapsar el hilo principal

Comment: La solución resultó hacer un reloadData() al terminar de leer el ciclo for

Comment: @AntonioLabra escribe tu mismo la respuesta y acéptala asi todos saben que la pregunta esta respondida.... 
Basicamente te paso esto pues la llamada que haces a la api es asyncrona y cuando se ejecuta el viewDidLoad aun no tienes los datos de los artistias... el código seria mas elegante si la función getArtistas le añades un callback y llamas al callback despues del for... luego en el viewdidLoad cuando llames al getArtistas dentro del calback y dentro del mainThread haces el reload de la tabla